# Deduplicate table while keeping the version vers column is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 columns: an id and an associated label.
Example:

```
id1,label1
id1,null
id2,label2
id3,null
```

I would like to deduplicate on the 1st column to keep the version where the label column is not null. But if the id appears only once, I want to keep the line no matter what, even though the label is null.
The output I would want with the example is:

```
id1,label1
id2,label2
id3,null
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (BigQuery)

```
select *
from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by id order by label desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXISTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=503deac9d8b71809bd745c225a2e2495))

```
delete 
  from <table1> d1 
 where d1.label is null 
   and exists ( select null 
                  from <table1> d2
                 where d2.id = d1.id 
                   and d2.label is not null 
              ) ;
```

EXISTS always returns True or False if the subslect *would have* returned at least 1 row. In this case it returns True only when there is a matching row where `label` is not null.  
Note: This does not work where there are multiple `id` each having a non-null `label`  nor each having a null label. So would not work on tuples  
('a',null) with ('a',null) nor the tuples  
('a','l1') with ('a','l1')